# How to manually set the GPS coordinates if the app is always asking user's location

Tags: google-places-api

What I have achieved so far is implement this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/Android-working-with-Google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

And now what I want is to implement a way in which `GPStracker` class which enables GPS for my device and detects where I am right now instead of my location, I want to show my app users a particular area let's say north of Bangalore (India); I know how to setup different types but I'm asking help in this

```
 i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
                    i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));
```

> gps.getLatitude ()

Is asking `GPSTracker.java` for coordinates and the location manager is simply pulling the same from my location, but what I want is fake the users location to some coordinates in the north of the city so that I can show them the results of that area (places -restaurants)